# TextWrangler does not highlight PHP & HTML codes properly

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, textwrangler

TextWrangler for Mac (v5.0.2) sometimes cannot highlight HTML & PHP codes (mixed) properly, given that the syntax is perfectly correct.

[image: Incorrect Highlighting]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: why downvote? Stack Overflow scope covers IDE questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can select "**PHP in HTML**" option from footer/status bar in TextWrangler as shown in the image. Moreover make sure extension of the file is php. [image]

Comment: "PHP in HTML" is selected by default, but still, highlighting is not available for some files...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for both TextWrangler and BBEdit. The work-around is to select another programming language on the bottom left, and then reselect `PHP in HTML`. It seems that some actions trigger this bug.

Comment: "PHP in HTML" is selected by default, but still, highlighting is not available for some files...

Comment: @Raptor What do you mean with 'is selected by default' ?

Comment: This sometimes crops up for me. I find Select-All/Copy/Paste seems to force a parsing re-style.